# How to deploy jupyterHub by kubeflow

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub, kubeflow

when i 'ks apply default -c jupyter' to deploy a jupyterHub, it always response following errors:

> [I 2019-01-09 14:28:52.866 JupyterHub app:871] Writing cookie_secret
>   to /jupyterhub_cookie_secret [I 2019-01-09 14:28:52.880
>   alembic.runtime.migration migration:117] Context impl SQLiteImpl. [I
>   2019-01-09 14:28:52.880 alembic.runtime.migration migration:122] Will
>   assume non-transactional DDL. [I 2019-01-09 14:28:52.895
>   alembic.runtime.migration migration:327] Running stamp_revision  ->
>   3ec6993fe20c [W 2019-01-09 14:28:53.034 JupyterHub app:955] No admin
>   users, admin interface will be unavailable. [W 2019-01-09 14:28:53.034
>   JupyterHub app:956] Add any administrative users to
>   `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config. [I 2019-01-09 14:28:53.034
>   JupyterHub app:983] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will
>   be allowed. [I 2019-01-09 14:28:53.059 JupyterHub app:1528] Hub API
>   listening on http://0.0.0.0:8081/hub/ [W 2019-01-09 14:28:53.060
>   JupyterHub proxy:415] 
>       Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
>       Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message. [W 2019-01-09 14:28:53.060 JupyterHub
>   proxy:456] Running JupyterHub without SSL.

I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...

> [I 2019-01-09 14:28:53.061 JupyterHub proxy:458] Starting proxy @
>   http://0.0.0.0:8000/ [E 2019-01-09 14:28:53.064 JupyterHub proxy:467]
>   Failed to find proxy ['configurable-http-proxy']
>       The proxy can be installed with `npm install -g configurable-http-proxy` [C 2019-01-09 14:28:53.065 JupyterHub
>   app:1535] Failed to start proxy
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1533, in start
>           yield self.proxy.start()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line
>   462, in start
>           self.proxy_process = Popen(cmd, env=env, start_new_session=True, shell=shell)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in **init**
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
>           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'configurable-http-proxy': 'configurable-http-proxy'

Answer (score 0):

try using ks apply default -c jupyterhub instead of ks apply default -c jupyter